# GarageBand - volume maxing out

Tags: garageband, sound-volume, recording

I have a multi-track mix in GarageBand. Each individual track has been recorded without clipping, and at no point during the song do any individual track volume levels go into the 'red area'.

However, at the loudest points the 'overall' track volume (on the bottom pane) goes into the red.

Is this a problem? Will it affect the quality of my exported track? If so, how can I deal with this except for individually lower the volume of every track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it does result in distortion or clipping. But you can also reduce the master volume:

[image]

If individual tracks were clipped before they were mixed to the master, they will still be clipped though. GarageBand always normalizes volume when you export a song, so you can reduce the master volume as much as you want.

Comment: Great thanks. What I didn't realise was the the master volume had an effect on the clipping in the mixed track.